# HTML5 type setting returns empty control text property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, asp.net-ajax

Have the following issue:
Working is Visual Studio 2010 on an asp.net/vb.net/ajax site and I'm trying to use HTML5 `type="email"` in an existing textbox control to generate an email targeted keyboard display for touchscreen devices...

```
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
...
    <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox" type="email"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Confirmation" runat="server" Text="Confirm" CssClass="btnBox" OnClick="Confirmation_Click" OnClientClick="setFocus();" />
...
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Confirmation" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

but in codebehind, the `Email.txt` is returning an empty string. If I remove the `type="email"` , all is good.

So that begs the question, I'm assuming that the type definition overrides the implied `type="text"` for the textbox control so how can I access the controls value for the async postback? Or can I at all?

```
msg = String.Format("Email:{0} ", Email.Text)
```

**UPDATE:**

Also tried using Request form with basic html element in conjunction with `Request.Form` and still could not retrieve the values when `type="email"`

```
...
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Email" name="Email" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox" type="email"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <input id="Email1" name="Email1" type="email" CssClass="txtBox"  />
...
```

Codebehind

```
...
        If Not Request.Form("Email1") Is Nothing Then
            temp = Request.Form("Email1").ToString
        End If
        If Not Request.Form("Email") Is Nothing Then
            temp = Request.Form("Email").ToString
        End If
...
```

but if I change the `type="text"` , all is fine...ugh...

Thanks for any guidance...

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh...Answering my own question...

So supposedly, `"TextMode`" in the textbox control will support modes of email and the like in Framework 4.5 (not tested on my side) but I can't upgrade at this time and so a little creative "work around" got me through.

So basically I added in a hidden field control and used JavaScript to inject the control with the value in the email field which enables my code behind to use the value set...see code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setFocus() {
    ...
        var hdnEmail = document.getElementById("HDNEmail");
        var emlEmail = document.getElementById("Email1");
        hdnEmail.value = emlEmail.value;
    ...
    }
</script>
...
    <input id="Email1" name="Email1" type="email" class="txtBox"  />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HDNEmail" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:HiddenField>
...

<asp:Button ID="ctlBTNConfirmation" runat="server" Text="Confirm" CssClass="btnBox" OnClick="Confirmation_Click" OnClientClick="setFocus();" />

...
```

Codebehind

```
...
temp = HDNEmail.Value
...
```

HTH someone but if anyone else has a more elegant solution...please add